# concatenating the formula with vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, formula, vlookup

I have concatenation formula which is following

```
=CONCATENATE("TABLE",B22)
```

I want this formula to read the value from cell B22, search this value in column D in sheet called "Tables" and return the value in Column B of same row.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Use INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of where you might think to use `VLOOKUP()`, but can't quite get it working.  `VLOOKUP()` only can work from left to right (meaning, the item you need to look up must be in a column left of the value you want to return).

However, `Index/Match` can be used to return an item regardless of what column the lookup value is in.

```
=INDEX('Tables'!$B:$B,MATCH(B22,'Tables'!$D:$D,0))
```

This will `MATCH()` cell `B22` to a row in `Tables` sheet, column D.  Then, return an `Index` (aka Value) from `Tables` sheet, column B of that same row.